# c++ switching between forward and reverse iteration

Tags: c++

I am trying to switch between forward and backward iteration to not have to duplicate the code within the iteration.

I tried using a ternary operator but it didn't work

```
auto begin = reverse ? mPxSize::reverse_iterator :
                       mPxSize::iterator;
```

(it was my understanding that it didn't like the different types) , so I am wondering if there is base version of the iterator I can declare such that the following would work

```
??? begin;
??? end;

if (reverse) {
    mPxSize::reverse_iterator begin = m_levels.rbegin();
    mPxSize::reverse_iterator end = m_levels.rbegin();
} else {
    mPxSize::const_iterator begin = m_levels.begin();
    mPxSize::const_iterator end = m_levels.begin();
}

for ( it = begin; it != end; it++ ) {
```

Can I predeclare the iterator with some base where I marked with ???. Or is there a simple way to make use of templates here (which I do not understand very well, I admit)

Comment: Templatize the iteration code on the type of iterator.

Comment: currently my function is defined 
     
double foo( const bool reverse ) { ... }
     
would I now have to create another function that I call from inside that function that looks something like
     
template <typename T_b, typename T_e>
double inner_foo( T_b begin, T_e end ) {
    for ( it = begin; it != end; it ++ ) { ... }

Comment: yes, move the innards of `foo` to a function template `bar`. Let `foo` call `bar` with the appropriate iterators of the appropriate type, for each case, forward or reverse.

Comment: ok, thanks. will give that a try

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using templates:

```
template<typename It>
void foo(It begin, It end) {
  for (It it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
    // ...
  }
}

void bar(std::vector<int>& m_levels, bool reverse) {
  if (reverse) {
    foo(m_levels.rbegin(), m_levels.rend());
  } else {
    foo(m_levels.begin(), m_levels.end());
  }
}
```

The idea is to move the logic into a helper function that's parameterized by the iterator type. It can then be called with either forward or reverse iterators.